# Ubuntu mysql error: Disk is full writing

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, disk-space-utilization

I had some mysql problems yesterday. I got "Too many connections" error on my sites because one of my script went a little bit crazy. After I fixed the connection problems I still got an error in mysql log.

> /usr/sbin/mysqld: Disk is full writing

I checked my disk usage with **"df -h"** and I got this result:

> Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/xvda1            3.0G  2.9G     0 100% /
>
> none                  530M  132K  530M   1% /dev
>
> none                  549M     0  549M   0% /dev/shm
>
> none                  549M   52K  549M   1% /var/run
>
> none                  549M     0  549M   0% /var/lock

So my **"/dev/xvda1"** file is full. I have no idea what this file doing, im really beginner on linux systems. My question is what should I do with it? Delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete that "file" you will be erasing your disk. /dev/xda1 is the the logical path that refers to your hard drive.

First of all check /var/log to see how big it is (go to the folder and do `du -sh`). Erase (extract first to another machine if you need them later) the logs of mysql if they are too big. My guess is your "crazy script" filled up your logs.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer Lucas, /var/log uses 971M I checked the biggest files in it.
rewrite.log - 144M
rewrite.log.1 - 641M
Should I erase them?

Comment: if there isn't anything in them you need, you can null them

Comment: Awesome thanks! It seems everything is working fine now. Have a nice day!

Comment: Running a vm with 3GB diskspace is risky if you don't have proper logrotation rules in place. I would suggest that you read up on log rotation and keep log files for no more than 7 days, depending on your requirements.